# Spring mvc integration with Apache Tiles 3 Using Java Configuration has Problems

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-tiles

**The problem is the that tiles configuration is not getting applied 
everytime.**
I have integrated Apache tiles 3 with spring MVC. I have used annotation based configuration of spring. The problem in the application is that the tiles definitions get applied on random basis. When I try to run the application, the tiles configuration that we have configured may or may not get applied.

I am using Apache tomcat 7. Is this problem related with server? Is this problem related with Configuration? Or If Any.

Here is my Code

**MVC Configuration**

```
        Annotation base Java Configuration using Spring
        @EnableWebMvc

        @Configuration

        @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.om.*" })

        public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
            }


            @Override
            public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.enable();
            }
            @Bean
            public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
                InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
                viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
                viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/layout/");
                viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
                return viewResolver;
            }


            @Bean
            public TilesViewResolver getTilesViewResolver() {
                TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
                tilesViewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
                return tilesViewResolver;
            }
            @Bean
            public TilesConfigurer getTilesConfigurer() {
                TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
                tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
                tilesConfigurer.setDefinitionsFactoryClass(TilesDefinitionsConfig.class);

                // Add apache tiles definitions
                TilesDefinitionsConfig.addDefinitions();

                return tilesConfigurer;
            }
        }
```

**MVCInitializer**

```
        public class MVCInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

            @Override
            protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
                return new Class[] { MVCConfig.class };
            }

            @Override
            protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected String[] getServletMappings() {
                return new String[] { "/" };
            }


        }
```

**TilesDefinitionsConfig**

```
        public final class TilesDefinitionsConfig implements DefinitionsFactory {

            private static final Map<String, Definition> tilesDefinitions = new HashMap<String,Definition>();
            private static final Attribute BASE_TEMPLATE = new Attribute("/WEB-INF/views/layout/defaultLayout.jsp");

            public Definition getDefinition(String name, Request tilesContext) {
                System.out.println("3");
                return tilesDefinitions.get(name);
            }

            /**
             * @param name <code>Name of the view</code>
             * @param title <code>Page title</code>
             * @param body <code>Body JSP file path</code>
             *
             * <code>Adds default layout definitions</code>
             */
            private static void addDefaultLayoutDef(String name, String title, String body) {
                Map<String, Attribute> attributes = new HashMap<String,Attribute>();

                attributes.put("title", new Attribute(title));
                attributes.put("header", new Attribute("/WEB-INF/views/layout/header.jsp"));
                attributes.put("menu", new Attribute("/WEB-INF/views/layout/menu.jsp"));
                attributes.put("body", new Attribute(body));
                attributes.put("footer", new Attribute("/WEB-INF/views/layout/footer.jsp"));

                tilesDefinitions.put(name, new Definition(name, BASE_TEMPLATE, attributes));
            }

            /**
             * <code>Add Apache tiles definitions</code>
             */
            public static void addDefinitions(){

                addDefaultLayoutDef("welcome", "welcome", "/WEB-INF/views/layout/welcome.jsp");
                addDefaultLayoutDef("personList", "viewPerson", "/WEB-INF/views/layout/personList.jsp");

            }
        }
```

**Controller**

```
        @Controller

        public class SpringTilesController {


            @RequestMapping(value="welcome")
            public ModelAndView index() {

                ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView();
                System.out.println("In Controller");
                model.setViewName("welcome");       
                return model;
            }

            @RequestMapping(value="viewPerson")
            public ModelAndView viewPersons(Model model) {
                Map<String, List<Person>> persons = 
                        new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();
                persons.put("persons", Person.createPersons());
                return new ModelAndView("personList", persons);
            }
        }
```

**Entity**

```
        public class Person {

            private String name, email;
            private int age;

            public Person(String name, String email, int age) {
                this.name = name;
                this.email = email;
                this.age = age;
            }

            public String getName() {return name;}
            public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

            public String getEmail() {return email;}
            public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}

            public int getAge() {return age;}
            public void setAge(int age) {this.age = age;}

            @Override
            public String toString()
            { 
                return String.format(
                    "Person [name = %s, email = %s, age = %d]", 
                        name, email, age);
            }

            public static List<Person> createPersons() {
                List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
                persons.add(new Person("Tousif", "tousif@mail.com", 32));
                persons.add(new Person("Asif", "asif@mail.com", 28));
                persons.add(new Person("Ramiz", "ramiz@mail.com", 26));
                persons.add(new Person("Rizwan", "rizwan@mail.com", 32));
                persons.add(new Person("Amol", "amol@mail.com", 33));
                persons.add(new Person("Ramdas", "ramdas@mail.com", 31));
                return persons;
            }
        }
```

**pom.xml**

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <groupId>com.om</groupId>
            <artifactId>TilesDemo</artifactId>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>TilesDemo Maven Webapp</name>
            <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

            <properties>
                <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
                <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
                <spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
                <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
                <javax.servlet.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet.version>
                <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
            </properties>


            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- jstl for jsp page -->


                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>${jstl.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Apache Tiles -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.5</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.5</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.5</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.5</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.5</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tiles-el</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.5</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>


                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>TilesDemo</finalName>
            </build>

        </project>
```

Keep The header,footer,menu as per the requirements.

This is **defaultLayout.jsp** page

```
        <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true"></tiles:insertAttribute></title>
        </head>
        <body style="background-color: #FFF">
            <div class="page">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
                <div class="content">
                    <div id="body">
                        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**footer.jsp**

```
    <hr />
    <div class="span-1 prepend-3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="span-16 last">
        <p>
            <b> Technology</b> 
            ( All rights Reserved)
        </p>
    </div>
```

**header.jsp**

```
    <div class="span-24">
        <img src="resources/images/images.png" 
            width="950" style="padding-top:10px;" />
    </div>
```

**menu.jsp**
Left side menu bar options

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <ul style="list-style:none;line-height:28px;">

        <li><spring:url value="/index" var="homeUrl" htmlEscape="true" />
            <a href="/TilesDemo/welcome">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li><spring:url value="/viewPerson" var="personListUrl" htmlEscape="true" />
            <a href="/TilesDemo/viewPerson">Person List</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

**welcome.jsp**
This is the body Page on which header, footer and menu will be applied.

```
    <div style="margin:10px;">
        <h3>SpringMVC - Tiles3 Integration tutorial</h3>
        <p>By:- XYZ</p>
    </div>
```

The problem is the that tiles configuration is not getting applied everytime.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in this project [Tiles configuration without xml](https://bitbucket.org/zxmax/spring-tiles/commits/3b58108b63f473fd0f81251d9ef0b7567caea9e2#chg-src/main/java/net/zxmax/config/TilesDefinitionConfig.java) the developer had a similar problem, the tiles configuration isn't working.

He found that if you call the view with the same name of the file.jsp, somethings going bad.

```
public static void addDefinitions(){

            addDefaultLayoutDef("welcome", "welcome", "/WEB-INF/views/layout/welcome.jsp");
            addDefaultLayoutDef("personList", "viewPerson", "/WEB-INF/views/layout/personList.jsp");
}
```

Try to use different name for the view and the file.jsp.
Try with

```
addDefaultLayoutDef("welcome", "Welcome", "/WEB-INF/views/layout/welcome.jsp");
```

Should work if the rest of the code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to define the view resolver's order precedence, something like this:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    //resolver.setOrder(2);

    return resolver;
}

//configuracion de apache tiles
@Bean
public TilesViewResolver getTilesViewResolver() {
    TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
    tilesViewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);

    // tiles view resolver va ha ser el primero en mostrarse
    tilesViewResolver.setOrder(1);

    return tilesViewResolver;
}
```